# Should a universal app have 4 copies of each image?

Tags: ios

In a universal app should I have a image.png, image@2x.png, image~ipad.png and image@2x~ipad.png for every image in my project?

Or should I just use my wider iPad images and have iOS scale them down to iPhone for me?

There's a lot of images so I'm a bit concerned about the file size...

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.allanberger.com/post/49938151321/how-to-make-your-apps-retina-ready) about images for retina. One image for everybody.

Comment: Are these full screen images or just icons? If they are full screen then you need a 5th for 4" iPhone/iPod touch devices. For icons you only need 2 of each.

Comment: Not full screen no...  but full width images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily but you can see code below. If you are targeting low res iPads and Low res iPhones you would have one set of icons for each. So if you are targeting iPad retina and iPhone retina that is on set of icons too so if you have an image called car.png and car@2x.png you would have 2 icons that cover all 4 models mentioned.

You can of course have images specific for iPad as the screen is larger then in your logic you would show either or depending on the device idiom..like below

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

//Device is iPhone
//This would give you low res icon for iPhone and if device is retina system will show it
UIImage *car = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Car.png"];
UIImageView *carImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:car];

}

else {
//Device is iPad
//This would give you low res icon for iPad and if device is retina system will show it
UIImage *carLarge = [UIImage imageNamed: @"CarLarge.png"];
UIImageView *carImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:carLarge];

}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow... so I should just use the 1536px wide iPad photo on both iPad and 640 pixel wide iPhone retina?

Comment: @sayguh if you are targeting ipad as well as iphone you will need x1 low res and x1 high res. If the image is too small for ipad then you would use the logic above to show a larger image for ipads only...so for example you would do x1 carLarge and a x1 carLarge@2x in the dimensions required for iPad

Comment: Yes but should my high res image be iPad retina width or iPhone retina width?   Should I just include iPad and have iOS handle downscale to iPhone?  Or should I just include iPhone and have iOS upscale to iPad dimensions?

Comment: @sayguh use my logic above then you have control of what to show. The choice of what you want to use is up to you but you should choose what makes sense i.e what looks good